# User matching query does not exist :Django

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-rest-framework

i am making a custom user login authentication system. i am getting error **User matching query does not exist** . i think that's come from ORM while fetching the query but i am not pretty sure why query does not exit while user matching. it would be great if anybody could me out what i am trying to solve. thank you so much in advance.

here below is my working code;

```
class LoginAPIView(APIView):

    def post(self, request, format=None):
        #gather the username and password provided by user
        data = request.data
        email = data['email']
        user_password = data['password']

        user_entered_password = user_password
        salt = "5gz"
        db_password = user_entered_password + salt
        hash_password = hashlib.md5(db_password.encode())
        print(hash_password.hexdigest())


        user_queryset = User.objects.all().get(Q(email__exact=email) & Q(password__exact=hash_password.hexdigest())).first()

        # user_ser = UserLoginSerializers(user_queryset,many=True)
        # user_data = user_ser.user_queryset

        user_id = []
        for u in user_queryset:
            _id = u.get('id')
            user_id.append(_id)

        if len(user_queryset) > 0:
            print(user_id)
            payload ={'user_id':user_id[0], 'exp':datetime.utcnow() + timedelta(seconds=JWT_EXP_DELTA_SECONDS)}
            jwt_token = jwt.encode(payload, JWT_SECRET, JWT_ALGORITHM)

            return Response({'token':jwt_token, "data":user_queryset}, status=status.HTTP_200_OK)
        else:
            return Response({"msg":"Invalid User"}, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```

Answer (score 1):

You do not have to do all this by yourself. Django has a function `authenticate` which take username and password and return you user.

```
from django.contrib.auth import authenticate

user = authenticate(username='your_username', password='you_password')
```

Django by default do authentication with username. If you want to use email for this, you can do one of these.

1. Use email of user as his username. With this, you will not have to do any changes in authentication system
2. Write custom authentication method. This will be like this.

code:

```
from django.contrib.auth import get_user_model
from django.contrib.auth.backends import ModelBackend

class EmailBackend(ModelBackend):
    def authenticate(self, username=None, password=None, **kwargs):
        UserModel = get_user_model()
        try:
            user = UserModel.objects.get(email=username)
        except UserModel.DoesNotExist:
            return None
        else:
            if user.check_password(password):
                return user
        return None
```

Then, set that backend as your auth backend in your settings:

```
AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS = ['path.to.auth.module.EmailBackend']
```

Comment: i know. as per i told you first i am making custom user authentication.